# Write an SQL query that reports the best seller by total sales price, If there is a tie, report them all

Tags: sql

I'm doing this leetcode question on SQL, and I have some questions that I wanted to ask you.

```
-- Table: Product

-- +--------------+---------+
-- | Column Name  | Type    |
-- +--------------+---------+
-- | product_id   | int     |
-- | product_name | varchar |
-- | unit_price   | int     |
-- +--------------+---------+
-- product_id is the primary key of this table.
-- Table: Sales

-- +-------------+---------+
-- | Column Name | Type    |
-- +-------------+---------+
-- | seller_id   | int     |
-- | product_id  | int     |
-- | buyer_id    | int     |
-- | sale_date   | date    |
-- | quantity    | int     |
-- | price       | int     |
-- +------ ------+---------+
-- This table has no primary key, it can have repeated rows.
-- product_id is a foreign key to Product table.
 

-- Write an SQL query that reports the best seller by total sales price, If there is a tie, report them all.

-- The query result format is in the following example:

-- Product table:
-- +------------+--------------+------------+
-- | product_id | product_name | unit_price |
-- +------------+--------------+------------+
-- | 1          | S8           | 1000       |
-- | 2          | G4           | 800        |
-- | 3          | iPhone       | 1400       |
-- +------------+--------------+------------+

-- Sales table:
-- +-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
-- | seller_id | product_id | buyer_id | sale_date  | quantity | price |
-- +-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+
-- | 1         | 1          | 1        | 2019-01-21 | 2        | 2000  |
-- | 1         | 2          | 2        | 2019-02-17 | 1        | 800   |
-- | 2         | 2          | 3        | 2019-06-02 | 1        | 800   |
-- | 3         | 3          | 4        | 2019-05-13 | 2        | 2800  |
-- +-----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------+

-- Result table:
-- +-------------+
-- | seller_id   |
-- +-------------+
-- | 1           |
-- | 3           |
-- +-------------+
-- Both sellers with id 1 and 3 sold products with the most total price of 2800.

-- Solution
Select a.seller_id
from
(select seller_id, 
rank() over(order by sum(price) desc) as rk
from sales
group by seller_id) a
where a.rk=1
```

This is my solution:

```
with x as 
(select seller_id, sum(price) as total
from(select distinct * from sales)
group by seller_id
)
select seller_id
from x
where total = (select max(total) from x)
```

My questions are:

1. First, is my solution true?
2. Is it necessary `select distinct * from sales` ? I do it whenever I see `This table has no primary key, it can have repeated rows`. The others didn't do it this way, so I'm wondering whether I did it correctly, and it bothered me a lot.
3. I'm new with SQL, and I write everything using only `select, from, where, group by, having, order by`. I'm not confident to use for example `rank()/row_number(),... over(partition by)...`, so my solutions are usually obviously longer than those given by others. I would like to know if the queries written as my way take indeed (a lot) more time to execute? (or how to know/compute the running time of a query?).

Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use `TOP(1) WITH TIES` to return not just 1 row, but all top rows with the same `total` value:

```
select TOP(1) WITH TIES
    seller_id
    ,sum(price) as total
from sales
group by seller_id
ORDER BY total DESC
```

No, you do not need `DISTINCT`. It does not just make the query slower, it may produce incorrect results. In your case it doesn't matter if the `sales` table has a primary key or not.

Your query would produce correct results if you remove `DISTINCT`.

If you use window function like `rank() over()` the query would likely be faster than your version, but a lot depends on the actual DBMS that you use, available indexes and other things. Most DBMS have methods to see how they run/execute the query. In SQL Server you can see the so-called execution plan, which gives very good idea of what the engine does to produce the result, how much data from which tables and how many times it reads, what transformations and calculations it performs.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Now I understood this sentence ```This table has no primary key, it can have repeated rows.```  means that a seller can sell the same product to a buyer in the same day with the same quantity and price, and each such activity is actually one time we have to count.

Comment: @Osiris, exactly. If you put `DISTINCT`, you will lose some of these values.